# Python Progress Bar in nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

I'm translating some linux log data to a CSV for data analytics. Some of the instructions take some time so, I thought I would put in a progress bar for each file that is being translated. However, when putting in a progress bar with either the progresspar2 or tqdm, my pandas dataframes and null. There's no data at all. When I remove the progress bar, everything works as it should.

Here is my CSV translating function:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser
from tqdm import trange
import os
import glob
import csv
import socket


def logsToCSV():
print("[+] Translating log to CSV")
log_file = open(CSV_FILE_PATH, "w", newline='')
csv_w = csv.writer(log_file)

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(LOGS_FILE_PATH, '*.txt')):       # Find all files in path with .txt
    data_file = open(filename, "r")
    file_length = len(data_file.readlines())

    for i in trange(file_length, desc='loop', leave=False):             # Progress Bar Via TQDM
        for new_line in data_file:

            new_line = line.strip().split(" ")
            date = str("%s %s %s" % (new_line[0], new_line[1], new_line[2])).strip()
            date = parser.parse(date)
            ip =str(new_line[5]).partition("/")
            ip = str(ip[0]).strip()
            try:
                url = str(new_line[7]).strip()
            except:
                url = None
            csv_w.writerow([date,ip,url])
```

[image]

TQDM is breaking something or I am implementing it incorrectly.

EDIT 1:

I figured it out. I was exhausting the file read during my readlines() to get the length. This works:

```
def logsToCSV():
print("[+] Translating log to CSV")
log_file = open(CSV_FILE_PATH, "w", newline='')
csv_w = csv.writer(log_file)
path, dirs, files = next(os.walk(LOGS_FILE_PATH))
log_num = len(files)
print(log_num)

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(LOGS_FILE_PATH, '*.txt')):       # Find all files in path with .txt
    data_file = open(filename, "r")
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        file_length = len(f.readlines())
    f.close()
    pbar = tqdm(total=file_length)
    for line in data_file:         
        new_line = line.strip().split(" ")
        date = str("%s %s %s" % (new_line[0], new_line[1], new_line[2])).strip()
        date = parser.parse(date)
        ip =str(new_line[5]).partition("/")
        ip = str(ip[0]).strip()
        try:
            url = str(new_line[7]).strip()
        except:
            url = None
        csv_w.writerow([date,ip,url])
        pbar.update(1)
    pbar.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

you can apply tqdm for your main loop :

from tqdm import tqdm 
for i in tqdam(condition):